# Add an alias automatically in Ubuntu after installation of Software using script(preferably Python3 or Bash)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

Is it possible to add an alias of a newly installed software in .bashrc in Ubuntu automatically after installation using a script (bash or python3 preferably for my personal use)? Alternatively, if this is not possible, is there any other way of going through the installed software database of Ubuntu(if any) for all the installed software adding each of their aliases in the .bashrc file if does not exist already or any other similar way?

Comment: Here's a Bash function I wrote to add permanent aliases on the fly, if it's helpful: https://github.com/wcarhart/Konphig/blob/master/.bash_functions/Linux/adda.sh

Comment: @wcarhart Thanks for the script. The function will work perfectly for me but I think I will have to manually give the alias arguments to the script for creating alias, right? But, is there any way for giving even the arguments, that is the alias name and executable path automatically for all the installed softwares?

Comment: Can you not just add your desired aliases to your `~/.bashrc` file? That will save them permanently

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you need to create a separate alias. Install software in your `PATH` and you don't need aliases or other hacks.